# Converting pandas dataframe to scipy sparse arrays

Tags: pandas, scipy, sparse

Converting pandas data frame with mixed column types -- numerical, ordinal as well as categorical -- to Scipy sparse arrays is a central problem in machine learning.

Now, if my pandas' data frame consists of only numerical data, then [I can simply do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459536/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-sparse-numpy-matrix-directly) the following to convert the data frame to sparse csr matrix:

```
scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(df.values)
```

and if my data frame consists of ordinal data types, I can handle them using [LabelEncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458645/label-encoding-across-multiple-columns-in-scikit-learn)

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(LabelEncoder)     
fit = df.apply(lambda x: d[x.name].fit_transform(x))
```

Then, I can again use the following and the problem is solved:

```
scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(df.values)
```

Categorical variables with a low number of values is also not a concern. They can easily be handled using pd.get_dummies (Pandas or Scikit-Learn versions).

My main concern is for categorical variables with a large number of values.

**The main problem:** How to handle categorical variables with a large number of values?

```
pd.get_dummies(train_set, columns=[categorical_columns_with_large_number_of_values], sparse=True)
```

also takes a lot of time.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084942/pandas-sparse-dataframe-to-sparse-matrix-without-generating-a-dense-matrix-in-m/38157234#38157234) seems to be giving interesting directions, but, it is not clear whether it handles all the data types efficiently.

Let me know if you know the efficient way. Thanks.